# Error generating chart because computed image is too large

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat, chart

I want to export a graph of type ui.chart.image.series in the GEE in CSV format.

This graphic is built into the browser after two different collections of images (one I named "Collection" and the other one from "imageCollection") are processed by a geospatial library (LANDTREND) after a click

```
Map.onClick(function(lonlat){

  var pixel = samplesVegPrimaCinquenta

  var collection = Collection
    .select(["NDVI_to_ajust"], ["ORIGINAL LANDSAT"])
    .merge(imageCollection.select(["NDVI"], ["LTGEE RESULT-INDEX NDVI"])
    )
    var options = {
        title : "Fit RMSE: " //+ (Math.round(collection * 100) / 100).toString()
      };

    var graph = (
    ui.Chart.image.series( 
      collection, 
      pixel,
      ee.Reducer.mean(), 30
      )
    .setOptions(options)
  );

      print(graph)
```

It is through the use of this library that the graph is so heavy to be plotted in the browser and therefore, I can not just click the "download in CSV" button available.

Just click on a point that the chart should be plotted, but an error occurs "Error generating chart: Computed image is too large". Here's the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e636899739bb6e2565587cd5799886be) .